# How to get to the closest reachable point if my destination is unreachable?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

Imagine a tile based game with unpassable terrain, your character can move with right click and will then move to the clicked tile. However it may occur that this tile cant be reached for some reason. My question now is is there a good algorithm that will do what most games do in these cases which is to let the character walk to the nearest reachable tile.
Is my best bet to just use A* and save the distance of every tile to the destination and then just walk to the nearest one? Would obviously be an exhaustive search if i wouldnt use any heuristics.

This image may illustrate the above scenario better, you click at the x but you cant reach it due to the wall so you rather walk to the red O which is approx. the closest tile to the x.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFSnp.png

Comment: You can assign very heavy weights to barrier tiles, do a shortest path, and then have the character move along the found path until it reaches a barrier tile.

Comment: There are some assumptions that could make this a lot easier, e.g., if the passable terrain is connected.

Comment: Dupe on a different SE: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35253/tweaking-astar-to-find-closest-location-to-unreachable-destination